# "My mom told me that this store is going to be hiring a cashier soon. " -- should mom be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I found the above sentence on a quiz. Mom should be capitalized because it is used as a  proper noun in the above sentence.

Comment: I think you write Mom when you are addressing your mom/Mom whether the word is at the start of or somewhere in a sentence. In other cases, it's OK whether you write Mom or mom.

Comment: @Khan *My Mom went to the store* does not follow standard, conventional usage; i.e., it is not "okay" if you want to pass a quiz that is following conventional, standard usage.

Answer (score 0):

You would capitalize 'mom' in two similar contexts:

1 speaking directly to one's mom

> Mom, you told me that this store is going to be hiring a cashier soon.

or

> You told me that this store is going to be hiring a cashier soon, Mom.

In this case, 'Mom' functions much like a name (for example, 'Alice').

2 without a determiner (in your case *my*)

> Mom told me that this store is going to be hiring a cashier soon.

or

> Yesterday, Mom told me that this store is going to be hiring a cashier soon.

Here you are not speaking to her, but you are still using 'Mom' as a name.

{Note: the second sentence in each example is provided so that the word 'mom' is not at the beginning of each sentence.}

You would not capitalize 'mom' in your sentence, because it is not functioning as a *name*.

Comment: Unfortunate examples, as Mom at the beginning of a sentence is always capitalized ;-)

Comment: @mic all right, point taken and extra examples given. thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you are referring to a specific person.